# Rails: validations are called more times than they should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails `5.0.0.beta2` in API mode. I've got the following models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: teams
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  competition_id :integer
#  name           :string
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#

class Team < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :competition, inverse_of: :teams, counter_cache: true

  has_many :user_teams, inverse_of: :team, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :teams, through: :user_teams

  validates :competition, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:competition] }

end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: competitions
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  classroom_id :integer
#  name         :string
#  start_at     :datetime
#  end_at       :datetime
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#

class Competition < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :classroom, counter_cache: true

  has_many :teams, inverse_of: :competition, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :start_at, timeliness: { type: :datetime }
  validates :end_at, timeliness: { after: :start_at, type: :datetime }

  scope :ordered, -> { order(:start_at) }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams

end



# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  email      :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :user_teams, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, inverse_of: :users, through: :user_teams

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  scope :ordered, -> { order(:name) }

end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: user_teams
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  team_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class UserTeam < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_teams
  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :user_teams, counter_cache: :users_count

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :team, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:user] }

  validate :user_in_correct_classroom,
           :only_one_team_per_competition

  def user_in_correct_classroom
    if self.user.coursed_classrooms.include?(self.team.competition.classroom)
      return
    end
    self.errors
        .add(:user, "needs to be coursing in the competition's classroom")
  end

  def only_one_team_per_competition
    user =
      User.joins(:teams)
          .find_by(id: self.user_id,
                   teams: { competition_id: self.team.competition_id })
    if user
      self.errors.add(:user, 'can only participate in one team per competition')
    end
  end

end
```

When I attempt to create a team:

```
#User with id=1 exists and is not present in any team
Competition.last.teams.create(name: "Rocket", user_ids: [1])
```

The `validate` methods defined in `team.rb` (`user_in_correct_classroom` and `only_one_team_per_competition`) are called 3 times each. The first two calls are successful, but on the last call for `only_one_team_per_competition`, the validation fails because Rails actually has performed the insert of the team and user in the competition. This rollbacks, of course, and the team is not actually saved in the database.

I don't understand why Rails is calling each validation three times. How can I fix this and why is it happening?

Comment: Who said that a beta is without errors? set a breakpoint and find out when the calls happen.

Comment: @Meier I also attempted to run this code with Rails 4.2.5 and had the same problem :(. Here you can find a script which attempts to reproduce the error https://gist.github.com/sauronnikko/1b7e3ec7b29b7b15c286. Unfortunately, it differs from the original code: the object gets saved. Still each validation is called thrice, which is weird